# Select value of list in the gridview edit button row

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, list, gridview

I originally had a gridview edit column that would allow me to edit the specific value in the row. I actually am not aloud use a datatable as an object however and converted my values into a list of objects. My question is, how can I convert my previous code:

```
Dim rowOfCustomers = GridView1.Rows(e.NewEditIndex)
sCompany = dtCustomer.Rows(rowOfCustomers.DataItemIndex)("Company")
sContact = dtCustomer.Rows(rowOfCustomers.DataItemIndex)("Contact")
sAddress1 = dtCustomer.Rows(rowOfCustomers.DataItemIndex)("Address1")
```

Into something I can use with my list. Maybe something along the lines of (except for the rowOfCustomer.DataItemIndex part):

```
sCompany = listOfCustomer.IndexOf(rowOfCustomers.DataItemIndex)("Contact")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to grab the index and item value.

```
sCompany = listOfCustomers.Item(rowIndex).Company
sContact = listOfCustomers.Item(rowIndex).Contact
sAddress1 = listOfCustomers.Item(rowIndex).Address1
```